# Parse log file while with between lines relation

Tags: file, parsing, logging, log4j

I have long log file that contents looks like

```
2015-06-13 20:58:32,278 60157353 [Thread-1] DEBUG ccc  - start PROC, will wait 30
2015-06-13 20:58:32,302 60157377 [Thread-1] DEBUG ccc  - stoping PROC 0
2015-06-13 20:58:42,339 60167414 [Thread-1] DEBUG ccc  - start PROC, will wait 30
2015-06-13 20:58:42,363 60167438 [Thread-1] DEBUG ccc  - stoping PROC 0
2015-06-13 20:58:52,378 60177453 [Thread-1] DEBUG ccc  - start PROC, will wait 30
2015-06-13 20:58:52,404 60177479 [Thread-1] DEBUG ccc  - stoping PROC 0
2015-06-13 20:58:52,430 60177506 [Thread-1] DEBUG ccc  - start PROC, will wait 30
```

I need to check time between `start PROC` and `stoping PROC` is not longer than 30 seconds.

Is it somehow possible do this with any log parser software?

Comment: It would be easy to do using your own [LogMX Parser](http://www.logmx.com/parser-dev). If you want to use LogMX log analyzer, I can help you.

Comment: Nice tool ! Yes, please help me with my task

Comment: OK I will post the Parser here. Could you please let me know what is the Log4j Pattern you are using in your Log4j configuration file? (it should be something like `%d{...} [%t] ... - %m`, but I don't know what "ccc" means in these logs, and how " - " is used before the message)

Comment: %d %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

Answer (score 1):

Using a [LogMX Parser](http://www.logmx.com/parser-dev), you can mark each start/stop couple as "Too long" (if there is more than 30s between `start PROC` and `stoping PROC`).

In the following Parser example, when the elapsed time is greater than 30s:

- The user-defined log entry field named "TooLong" is set to "x" (else, it is empty) *=> can easily filter/sort/search using this field*
- The `stoping PROC` entry is marked as ERROR to appear in red *=> can quickly see it*

Of course, you can adjust this code according to your needs.

To use this parser:

1. Copy the following code in a new file `<LogMX_dir>/parsers/src/sample/parser/VicoParser.java`
2. Compile it using Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA, Maven, Gradle, or Ant using files in `<LogMX_dir>/parsers` (see [LogMX documentation](http://www.logmx.com/parser-dev))
3. Add this Parser in LogMX using menu "Tools" > "Options" > "Parsers" > green "+" button > "Java class Parser" tab > choose `<LogMX_dir>/parsers/classes/sample.parser/VicoParser`

*VicoParser.java:*

```java
package sample.parser;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import com.lightysoft.logmx.business.ParsedEntry;
import com.lightysoft.logmx.mgr.LogFileParser;

/**
 * Sample LogMX Parser able to parse a log file with multi-line support, Absolute/Relative Date support,
 * and detection of too-long elapsed time between too specific entries.<BR/>
 * 
 * Log4j Pattern for this log format is:
 * %d %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
 * 
 * Here is an example of log file suitable for this parser:<BR/>
 * 2015-06-13 20:58:32,278 60157353 [Thread-1] DEBUG ccc  - start PROC, will wait 30
 * 2015-06-13 20:58:32,302 60157377 [Thread-1] DEBUG ccc  - stoping PROC 0
 * 2015-06-13 20:58:42,339 60167414 [Thread-1] DEBUG ccc  - start PROC, will wait 30
 * 2015-06-13 20:58:42,363 60167438 [Thread-1] DEBUG ccc  - stoping PROC 0
 * 2015-06-13 20:58:52,378 60177453 [Thread-1] DEBUG ccc  - start PROC, will wait 30
 * 2015-06-13 20:58:52,404 60177479 [Thread-1] DEBUG ccc  - stoping PROC 0
 * 2015-06-13 20:58:52,430 60177506 [Thread-1] DEBUG ccc  - start PROC, will wait 30
 */
public class VicoParser extends LogFileParser {
    /** Current parsed log entry */
    private ParsedEntry entry = null;

    /** Entry date format (this is Log4j default ISO-8601) */
    private static SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS");

    /** Mutex to avoid that multiple threads use the same Date formatter at the same time */
    private final Object DATE_FORMATTER_MUTEX = new Object();

    /** Pattern for entry begin */
    private final static Pattern ENTRY_BEGIN_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
    // %d
        "^(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2},\\d+?)\\s+?"
        // %-4r [%t] %-5p
                + "(\\d+?)\\s+?\\[(.*?)\\]\\s+?(.*?)\\s+?"
                // %c %x - %m
                + "(.*?) (.*?) - (.*)$");

    /** Buffer for Entry message (improves performance for multi-lines entries)  */
    private StringBuilder entryMsgBuffer = null;

    /////////////  Elapsed-Time computation  //////////// 
    /** Log entry message used for T0 (elapsed time calculation) */
    private static final String LOG_MESSAGE_T0 = "start PROC";

    /** Log entry message used for T1 (elapsed time calculation) */
    private static final String LOG_MESSAGE_T1 = "stoping PROC";

    /** Last encountered T0 entry */
    private ParsedEntry prevT0Entry = null;

    /** Max allowed time between entries, before raising "TooLong" flag */
    private static final long MAXIMUM_DELTA_T = 30000L; // 30s (30,000 ms)

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /** Key of user-defined field "Timestamp" (internal, not displayed) */
    private static final String EXTRA_FIELD_KEY__TIMESTAMP = "Timestamp";

    /** Key of user-defined field "NDC" */
    private static final String EXTRA_FIELD_KEY__NDC = "NDC";

    /** Key of user-defined field "TooLong" */
    private static final String EXTRA_FIELD_KEY__TOOLONG = "TooLong";

    /** User-defined fields names */
    private static final List<String> EXTRA_FIELDS_KEYS = Arrays.asList(EXTRA_FIELD_KEY__NDC,
        EXTRA_FIELD_KEY__TOOLONG);


    /** 
     * Returns the name of this parser
     * @see com.lightysoft.logmx.mgr.LogFileParser#getParserName()
     */
    @Override
    public String getParserName() {
        return "Vico Parser";
    }

    /**
     * Returns the supported file type for this parser
     * @see com.lightysoft.logmx.mgr.LogFileParser#getSupportedFileType()
     */
    @Override
    public String getSupportedFileType() {
        return "Vico log files";
    }

    /**
     * Process the new line of text read from file 
     * @see com.lightysoft.logmx.mgr.LogFileParser#parseLine(java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    protected void parseLine(String line) throws Exception {
        // If end of file, records last entry if necessary, and exits
        if (line == null) {
            recordPreviousEntryIfExists();
            return;
        }

        Matcher matcher = ENTRY_BEGIN_PATTERN.matcher(line);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            // Record previous found entry if exists, then create a new one
            prepareNewEntry();

            entry.setDate(matcher.group(1));
            entry.setThread(matcher.group(3));
            entry.setLevel(matcher.group(4));
            entry.setEmitter(matcher.group(5));
            String logMsg = matcher.group(7);

            // Save relative timestamp (in ms), for "getRelativeEntryDate()", but also to compute elapsed 
            // time between two specific log entries (faster than parsing complete absolute date)
            long timestamp = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2), 10);

            entryMsgBuffer.append(logMsg);
            entry.getUserDefinedFields().put(EXTRA_FIELD_KEY__NDC, matcher.group(6)); // save NDC
            entry.getUserDefinedFields().put(EXTRA_FIELD_KEY__TIMESTAMP, timestamp); // save Timestamp

            if (logMsg.startsWith(LOG_MESSAGE_T0)) {
                if (prevT0Entry != null) {
                    System.err.println("Warning: found [" + LOG_MESSAGE_T0 + "] not followed by ["
                            + LOG_MESSAGE_T1 + "]");
                }
                prevT0Entry = entry;
            } else if (logMsg.startsWith(LOG_MESSAGE_T1)) {
                if (prevT0Entry == null) {
                    System.err.println("Warning: found [" + LOG_MESSAGE_T1 + "] not preceded by ["
                            + LOG_MESSAGE_T0 + "]");
                } else {
                    long prevT0 = (Long) prevT0Entry.getUserDefinedFields().get(
                        EXTRA_FIELD_KEY__TIMESTAMP);
                    if (timestamp - prevT0 > MAXIMUM_DELTA_T) {
                        entry.getUserDefinedFields().put(EXTRA_FIELD_KEY__TOOLONG, "x"); // Flag this entry as "TooLong"
                        prevT0Entry.getUserDefinedFields().put(EXTRA_FIELD_KEY__TOOLONG, "x"); // Flag this entry as "TooLong"
                        // Change log entry Level (note: cannot change Level of T0 entry because it has been already processed by LogMX)
                        entry.setLevel("ERROR");
                    }
                    prevT0Entry = null;
                }
            }
        } else if (entry != null) {
            entryMsgBuffer.append('\n').append(line); // appends this line to previous entry's text
        }
    }

    /** 
     * Returns the ordered list of user-defined fields to display (given by their key), for each entry.
     * @see com.lightysoft.logmx.mgr.LogFileParser#getUserDefinedFields()
     */
    @Override
    public List<String> getUserDefinedFields() {
        return EXTRA_FIELDS_KEYS;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a relative Date for the given entry 
     * @see com.lightysoft.logmx.mgr.LogFileParser#getRelativeEntryDate(com.lightysoft.logmx.business.ParsedEntry)
     */
    @Override
    public Date getRelativeEntryDate(ParsedEntry pEntry) throws Exception {
        Long timestamp = (Long) pEntry.getUserDefinedFields().get(EXTRA_FIELD_KEY__TIMESTAMP);
        return new Date(timestamp);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the absolute Date for the given entry 
     * @see com.lightysoft.logmx.mgr.LogFileParser#getAbsoluteEntryDate(com.lightysoft.logmx.business.ParsedEntry)
     */
    @Override
    public Date getAbsoluteEntryDate(ParsedEntry pEntry) throws Exception {
        synchronized (DATE_FORMATTER_MUTEX) { // Java date formatter is not thread-safe
            return dateFormat.parse(pEntry.getDate());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Send to LogMX the current parsed log entry
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private void recordPreviousEntryIfExists() throws Exception {
        if (entry != null) {
            entry.setMessage(entryMsgBuffer.toString());
            addEntry(entry);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Send to LogMX the current parsed log entry, then create a new one
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private void prepareNewEntry() throws Exception {
        recordPreviousEntryIfExists();
        entry = createNewEntry();
        entryMsgBuffer = new StringBuilder(80);
        entry.setUserDefinedFields(new HashMap<String, Object>(4));
    }
}
```

And here is what I get:
[image]

Note: you can sort/filter log entries using the field named "TooLong" by clicking on its column (mouse left/middle button, or menu "Filter" > "Show filtering bar")

Comment: Really cool answer! Thanks for the detailed code example. With a few (maybe not just a few, but anyways :) ) tweaks I can use for my own custom log system. Thank you again @xav

Comment: Oh and [this resource](http://www.logmx.com/p_parser_dev.php) is quite useful to help actually implement that in a Java IDE (Eclipse or IntelliJ)